# How to subset a table by date and sequence?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I need to subset a table by several conditions.

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("A","A","B","B","B","C"), seq=c(1,2,1,2,3,1), date=as.Date(c("2005-10-01", "2008-12-01","2001-03-05","2004-05-09","2008-10-15","2010-02-27")), value=c(20,12,80,55,77,57))


  id  | seq  |     date    | value
 --------------------------------
  A   |  1   | 2005-10-01  |  20
  A   |  2   | 2008-12-01  |  12
  B   |  1   | 2001-03-05  |  80
  B   |  2   | 2004-05-09  |  55
  B   |  3   | 2008-10-15  |  77
  C   |  1   | 2010-02-27  |  57
```

I need a method to return exactly one value for each id. Specifically, the value with the **highest sequence** with a **date less or equal a given date**. Given say `2004-07-01`, it should return:

```
id  |  value
--------------
A   |   20
B   |   55
C   |   57
```

(Note that in the special case where the date is less than the first date, it should return the seq=1, not nothing)

Is this possible? In one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
with(df[df$date >= as.Date("2004-07-01"),], do.call("rbind", lapply(split(data.frame(id, value,seq), id), function(x) x[which.max(x$value), c("id", "value")])))
  id value
A  A    20
B  B    77
C  C    57
```

Comment: I noticed the result being different, but it is becasue the value 55 for id B is before the desired start point, or am I missing something?

Comment: The given date is rather the "end-point". I need the last post **before** the given date. (_Unless_ there are no posts before the given date. Then I just want the first post)

Comment: The last post before the given date, or the post with the highest value of seq, before the given date?